# Disable specific dates in Fengyuanchen Datepicker jQuery plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, datepicker

Using this datepicker plugin https://github.com/fengyuanchen/datepicker I am enabling only Tuesdays at the moment, how can I disable specific dates? E.g October 31sth and December 19th?

I have tried

```
if (date.getDate() == 31/10/2017) {
return false; }
```

**Current:**

```
var now = Date.now();
$('input#form-input-chooseADate').datepicker({
    format: 'dd/mm/yyyy',
    autoHide: true,
    startDate : '10/10/2017',
    filter: function(date) {
        if (date.getDay() != 2) {
          return false; // Enable Tuesdays only
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 3):

Hope this Helps!

use [inArray](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.inArray/) to disable specific dates

```
var array = ["18/10/2017", "19/10/2017"];//dates to disable
var now = Date.now();
$('input#form-input-chooseADate').datepicker({
    format: 'dd/mm/yyyy',
    autoHide: true,
    startDate : '10/10/2017',
    filter: function(date) {
        $thisDate = date.getDate() + "/" + (date.getMonth() + 1) + "/" + date.getFullYear();
        if ($.inArray($thisDate, array) != -1 && date.getDay() != 2) {
          return false; 
        }
    }
});
```